# Can I change the ShadowStorage volume via cmd when if no drive letter assigned?

Tags: windows

I work for a backup software company and some times our customer's backups fail if there's insufficient space on a volume to store the shadow copy data. The solution is to either increase the maximum shadow copy size. However, on small partitions, this isn't always possible. So the next solution is to change the volume the shadow copy is stored on. This can be done for example with `vssadmin resize ShadowStorage /for=E: /on=C: /MaxSize=10%`.

However, I can't figure out how to use this command for volumes without a drive letter.

```
vssadmin list shadowstorage

Shadow Copy Storage association
   For volume: (\\?\Volume{541d914f-6291-451b-81c3-12694237c828}\)\\?\Volume{541d914f-6291-451b-81c3-12694237c828}\
   Shadow Copy Storage volume: (\\?\Volume{541d914f-6291-451b-81c3-12694237c828}\)\\?\Volume{541d914f-6291-451b-81c3-12694237c828}\
   Used Shadow Copy Storage space: 0 bytes (0%)
   Allocated Shadow Copy Storage space: 0 bytes (0%)
   Maximum Shadow Copy Storage space: 320 MB (32%)
```

This same question was asked at the link below, but I already tried that syntax and it gave me `Error: Invalid option.`
https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/249ykh/trouble_with_shadow_storage_allocation/

My syntax using the same volume noted in the list command above:

```
vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=\\?\Volume{541d914f-6291-451b-81c3-12694237c828}\ /on=C: /MaxSize=10%
```

My laptop is Windows10.
I even tried assigning the WinRE volume a drive letter in diskpart. Diskpart and the File Explorer did see the new drive letter assignment, but Disk Management and the vssadmin list shadowstorage commands did not display this drive letter assignment. I thought that was interesting but I don't know why there's a disconnect.

I also tried this on a 2012R2 Server and got the following:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=\\?\Volume{7a18301b-61
2f-40bb-8ed6-9df57f300585}\ /on=C: /MaxSize=35%
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2013 Microsoft Corp.

Error: The specified volume shadow copy storage association was not found.
```

Then I tried doing the same thing using `... /for=E: /on=C: /MaxSize=35%` and received the same error. So now I'm just thinking there's a big gap in knowledge I'm missing on how this works.

On Server 2012R2, I can right click on a drive and click 'Configure Shadow Copies...' and change the association that way. But I don't see this option in Windows 10 and ideally I would like to be able to do this all via cmd or PowerShell.

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0):

```
vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=\\?\Volume{541d914f-6291-451b-81c3-12694237c828}\ /on=C: /MaxSize=10%
```

The command shown above works. It needs to be run from an elevated command prompt (not PS which is where I was trying this.) I used this on Server 2012, PS v4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from powershell with some quoting:

```
vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for="\\?\Volume{541d914f-6291-451b-81c3-12694237c828}\" /on=C: /MaxSize=10%
```